# How to set keys with the name of each histogram bar in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, legend

I have this dataset:

```
"name01","9.3","1"
"name02","8.68","2"
"name03","8.57142857143","3"
"name04","8.45454545455","4"
"name05","8.34518174511","5"
"name06","8.22222222222","6"
"name07","8.16666666667","7"
"name08","8.14053254438","8"
"name09","8.11111111111","9"
"name10","7.93939393939","10"
"name11","7.92307692308","11"
"name12","7.89285714286","12"
"name13","7.81818181818","13"
"name14","7.8125","14"
"name15","7.77777777778","15"
"name16","7.70588235294","16"
"name17","7.66101694915","17"
"name18","7.65714285714","18"
"name19","7.45054945055","19"
"name20","7.425","20"
"name21","7.30769230769","21"
"name22","7.20689655172","22"
```

and I'd like to plot an histogram with all "nameXX" on the legend. Using the following code I have two issues:

- only one key is shown and its value is "9.3" instead of "name01"
- no other keys are shown

Gnuplot code:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 1600,600
set output 'myhistogram.png'
set title "My Histogram" font "Arial, 14"
set auto x
set yrange [0:*]
set style data histogram
set key invert reverse Left outside
set key autotitle columnheader
set ytics 1
unset xtics
set style fill solid border -1
set palette color model HSV
set palette defined (0 0 1 1,1 1 1 1)
set palette defined ( 0 0 1 0, 1 0 1 1, 6 0.8333 1 1, 7 0.8333 0 1)
unset colorbox
set boxwidth 0.8
set datafile separator ","

stats "password_length_area.csv" using 2 nooutput
set yrange [0:STATS_max * 1.2]
plot "password_length_area.csv" using 0:2:3:key(1) with boxes lc palette
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to plot individual boxes separately via the `for` statement. As for the key, the example below saves in each iteration the string value of the first column into a variable `msg` which is then used for the corresponding `title`:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 1600,600
set output 'myhistogram.png'
set title "My Histogram" font "Arial, 14"
set auto x
set yrange [0:*]

#set style data histogram
set key invert reverse Left outside
#set key autotitle columnheader

set ytics 1
unset xtics
set style fill solid border -1
set palette color model HSV
set palette defined (0 0 1 1,1 1 1 1)
set palette defined ( 0 0 1 0, 1 0 1 1, 6 0.8333 1 1, 7 0.8333 0 1)
unset colorbox
set boxwidth 0.8
set datafile separator ","

fName = "password_length_area.csv"
stats fName using 2 nooutput

set yrange [0:STATS_max * 1.2]

N = STATS_records
msg = ''
plot for [i=0:N-1] \
    fName every ::i::i \
    using (i):2:(msg = stringcolumn(1), column(3)) \
    with boxes lc palette t msg
```

This then produces:
[image]